# How can I serve an HTML file from Azure blob storage in a web app using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

Apologies if this is straight-forward, I'm very much not a software developer!

I have a web app using Node (Node 16.17.0, npm 8.13.2). I have HTML files that I upload to an Azure Blob Storage container.

I would like to serve the files directly from the storage container to a user.

In the past, I've typically used something like this:

```
app.get(
    '/analysis/example', async (req, res) => {
        const a = path.join(__dirname + '/app/analysis/example_file.html');
        res.sendFile(a);
    }
);
```

However, I'm struggling a bit finding the appropriate documentation or examples to serve a file from blob storage.

I **have** managed to find a way to print the list of files and the file itself to the console - so I know for sure that I've managed to gain access properly (Azure documentation is quite good) - but I'm just not sure how to make sure the file is in an appropriate state to be served back.

I've tried this:

```
// GAIN ACCESS TO THE APPROPRIATE STORAGE ACCOUNT

const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(
    process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
);
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(
    process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER
);
const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(
    process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_BLOB
);

// A FUNCTION TO HELP TURN THE STREAM INTO TEXT (TURN THIS INTO SOMETHING ELSE?)

async function streamToText(readable) {
    readable.setEncoding('utf8');
    let data = '';
    for await (const chunk of readable) {
        data += chunk;
    }
    return data;
};

// SERVE THE HTML FILE

app.get(
    '/analytics/example', async (req, res) => {

            // THIS CHUNK SUCCESSFULLY LISTS AVAILABLE FILES IN THE CONSOLE
            // for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
            //     console.log("\t", blob.name);
            // };

            const blobDownload = await blobClient.download(0);
            const blob = await streamToText(blobDownload.readableStreamBody);
            res.sendFile(blob);

        }
    }
);
```

I've also tried the final chunk below (I found an online resource that mentioned that DOMParser wouldn't work with Node):

```
// SERVE THE HTML FILE

app.get(
    '/analytics/example', async (req, res) => {

            // THIS CHUNK SUCCESSFULLY LISTS AVAILABLE FILES IN THE CONSOLE
            // for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
            //     console.log("\t", blob.name);
            // };

            const blobDownload = await blobClient.download(0);
            const blob = await streamToText(blobDownload.readableStreamBody);
            
            var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
            let parser = new DOMParser();
            let doc = parser.parseFromString(blob, 'text/html');
            res.sendFile(doc.body);

        }
    }
);
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Could you serve the files directly from blob storage instead?

Comment: I'd prefer the browser to not show the file URL, but wasn't sure that would be possible? I did try just linking directly to the URL in the first place - but that didn't seem to work. I perhaps didn't spend long enough fighting it though.

Comment: Yes it would be a different URL to your app and be specific to the blob, but just thought it worth mentioning that a blob can be public and have [a custom DNS name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?tabs=azure-portal).

Comment: Yeah, thanks - appreciate the help (the fact that you even knew to mention it means you know more than I do! :D )

I've just worked it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just worked it out - it was simply the "res.sendFile" part, should have been "res.send".

The below is the correct working code to read the file from Azure Storage and serve it back to the app.

```
// GAIN ACCESS TO THE APPROPRIATE STORAGE ACCOUNT

const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(
    process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
);
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(
    process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER
);
const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(
    process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_BLOB
);

// A FUNCTION TO HELP TURN THE STREAM INTO TEXT (TURN THIS INTO SOMETHING ELSE?)

async function streamToText(readable) {
    readable.setEncoding('utf8');
    let data = '';
    for await (const chunk of readable) {
        data += chunk;
    }
    return data;
};

// SERVE THE HTML FILE

app.get(
    '/analytics/example', async (req, res) => {
            const blobDownload = await blobClient.download(0);
            const blob = await streamToText(blobDownload.readableStreamBody);
            res.send(blob);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: You should also be able to pipe a stream directly through rather than chunking it in memory: `blobDownload.readableStreamBody.pipe(res)`

Comment: Thanks - will give that a try later on!